# E-Unification: “Goal seeking” pattern matching between directed trees

Tags: algorithms, trees, unification

### Preamble

Suppose we have some symbols `x`, `y`, ... and wildcards `(ξ)`, `(ζ)`, ... which have any meaning. Wildcards are said to ‘match’ any symbol: *wildcard `(ξ)` matches symbol `x` under the mapping `{(ξ): x}`*. Now suppose we can construct directed trees from these symbols and wildcards. The notion of matching should extend to these trees, like this:

```
  x                 x       
 / \               / \      
a   y   matches  (ξ)  y   under the mapping {(ξ): a, (ζ): b}.
   / \               / \    
  z   b             z  (ζ)
```

It is easy to implement an algorithm which takes two trees like those above and gives the necessary mapping. (Does it have a name?)

I want to introduce certain ‘equivalence relations’ `<n>` between trees. For instance, if I wanted to capture the notion of the symbol `f` being commutative and associative, I could write:

```
       f         f
<1>:  / \   =   / \     # commutativity f(ξ, ζ) = f(ζ, ξ)
    (ξ) (ζ)   (ζ) (ξ)

        f         f
       / \       / \
<2>:  f  (χ) = (ξ)  f   # associativity f(f(ξ, ζ), χ) = f(ξ, f(ζ, ξ))
     / \           / \
   (ξ) (ζ)       (ζ) (χ)
```

This is where things get interesting, because I now want to implement a more intelligent matching algorithm which, given a set of equivalence relations like those above, is able to perform ‘indirect’ matches like this:

```
  f                          f          
 / \  (indirectly) matches  / \  under the mapping {(ξ): x}...
y   x                     (ξ)  y                     

                f  <1>  f                            f
   ...because  / \  =  / \  which directly matches  / \ .
              y   x   x   y                       (ξ)  y
```

### Question

How would one go about finding an algorithm which is able to transform a given tree (via given rules) so that it ‘matches’ another tree?

Is there a name for this kind of problem?

---

### More examples

Matches aren’t always unique. Ideally, the algorithm should be able to find all of them.

```
   f                 f
  / \               / \
 x   f   matches   f  (ξ)  under {(ξ): y, (ζ): z} or {(ξ): z, (ζ): y}...
    / \           / \
   y   z        (ζ)  x

         ...using rules <1> and <2>.
```

*A quintessential demonstrative example:*

For brevity, define the symbols `1`, `2`, `3`, ... in terms of `0` and a unary symbol `s`:

```
1 = s(0), 2 = s(s(0)), 3 = s(s(s(0)))...
```

Now, define two transformation rules `s(n) = +(n, 1)` and `s(+(n, m)) = +(n, s(m))`:

```
       +      s
<1>:  / \  =  |
    (n)  1   (n)

     s       +
<2>: |  =   / \
     +    (n)  s
    / \        |
  (n)  (m)    (m)
```

Check this out:

```
            +
5 matches  / \  under {(ξ): 2}, because...
          3  (ξ)
                     <1>          <2>
...5 = s(4) = s(s(3)) = s(+(3, 1)) = +(3, s(1)) = +(3, 2) which matches 5 with {(ξ): 2}.

   (as trees:)
       s   s  <1>  s  <2>   +       +                  +
...5 = | = |   =   |   =   / \  =  / \  which matches / \  with {(ξ): 2}.
       4   s       +      3   s   3   2              3  (ξ)
           |      / \         |
           3     3   1        1
```

---

(I apologise for the size of this question. I don’t have a background, so feel free to improve this post.)

Perhaps you can direct me to some reading, or set me off in the right direction? Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

This is called [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).  There is a one-to-one correspondence between terms and trees; the tree is the parse tree of a corresponding term.  It sounds like you want the most general unifier.  There are standard algorithms for solving this.  However, this doesn't handle equivalence relations like commutativity or associativity.  [E-unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#E-unification) might be what you are looking for.